# Get a Table column value into variable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, itemtemplate

I am getting a `itemtemplate` field of form view using a table. I need to get a `username` into a variable so that I can delete a particular `row.Username` is unique.

**This is my code:**

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>User Name:</b></td>
            <td><%# Eval("UserName") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Password:</b></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Password") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>First Name:</b></td>
            <td><%# Eval("FirstName") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Last Name:</b></td>
            <td><%# Eval("LastName") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton"
                                    Text="Edit"
                                    CommandName="Edit"
                                    RunAt="server"/>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton"
                                    Text="New"
                                    CommandName="New"
                                    RunAt="server"/>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton"
                                    Text="Delete"
                                    CommandName="Delete"
                                    RunAt="server"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

How can I do it in `C#`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a server control instead, for example a `Label`, then you can find it via `item.FindControl`:

aspx:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right"><b>User Name:</b></td><td>
        <asp:Label Id="LblUserName" runat="server"
             Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>'></asp:label>
    </td>
</tr>
.......
<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton"
    Text="Delete"
    CommandName="Delete"
    RunAt="server"
    OnCommand="DeleteButton_Command" />
```

codebehind:

```
void DeleteButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    if(e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        LinkButton btnDelete = (LinkButton)sender;
        var item = (FormViewItem)btnDelete.NamingContainer;
        Label LblUserName = (Label)item.FindControl("LblUserName");
        String userName = LblUserName.Text;
    }
}
```